# JavaScript empty Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

Im new to JavaScript, and im trying to figure out if this is the correct syntax for an array method that takes in an empty arrow function as an argument. This code block will be used as a callback function.

this is what I have.

```
const storyWords...
storyWords.forEach( () => {});
```

Just want to know if this is correct, and any additional feedback would be great! Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve this way?  What is the purpose?

Comment: Yes `() => {}` is so called noop function, same as `function() {}`

Comment: See the documentation for [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). You might also be in interested in using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212347/javascript-empty-arrow-function#comment131025672_74212347) "noop" is short for [no operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) (do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function will execute as many times as there are entries in storyWords array:

```js
['word','another'].forEach(()  => {console.log('execute')})
```

```
['word','another'].forEach(()  => {console.log('execute')})

execute
execute
```

If you actually want to process the words, you should pass each word as an argument instead of an empty array list:

```js
['word','another'].forEach((word)  => {console.log('execute ' + word)})
```

If storyWords is an object it will fail, because forEach doesn't work on objects.